# Part of my url get's removed upon adding a relative path

Tags: c#, .net, uri, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a base url `http://some.com/url/that/does/something` and a relative url `this/is/a/specific/path`.

Whenever I try to combine the two using `new Uri(baseUrl, relativeUrl)` some part of the base url gets cropped. The results with above example is

```
var baseUrl = new Uri("http://some.com/url/that/does/something")
var relativeUrl = "this/is/a/specific/path";
var Url = new Uri(baseUrl, relativeUrl);
// result is = http://some.com/url/that/does/this/is/a/specific/path
```

As you might have noticed the `something` disappeared.

How am I supposed to solve this?

I couldn't find any examples by Googling or searching here on Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Try with a trailing '/' on the base URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing **/**

Here is Your Answer

```
        var baseUrl = new Uri("http://some.com/url/that/does/something/");
        var relativeUrl = "this/is/a/specific/path";
        var Url = new Uri(baseUrl, relativeUrl);
```